# upgrade opencv on raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I currently have opencv 2.4.1 on my rapsberry pi and have been looking for a way to upgrade it to 2.4.10 which is the latest stable release. Will I have to do a fresh install or is there a way to upgrade it?

Comment: you will have to download the source and compile it http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Comment: Will I have to manually remove the install I have or will this overwrite it?

Comment: just recompiling should be fine

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham, put it as an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to  download the source and compile:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.10/opencv-2.4.10.zip
```

The instructions for linux from the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) are basically:

```
Create a temporary directory, which we denote as <cmake_binary_dir>, where you want to put the generated Makefiles, project files as well the object files and output binaries.
Enter the <cmake_binary_dir> and type
cmake [<some optional parameters>] <path to the OpenCV source directory>
For example
cd ~/opencv
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
Enter the created temporary directory (<cmake_binary_dir>) and proceed with:
make
sudo make install
```

There is a thorough [tutorial](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) for ubuntu 14.04 that may also be useful.